# How to convert blogger xml to Wordpress xml?

Tags: xml, wordpress, blogger

I have a blogger xml file size 67MB and i want to convert wordpress xml. how it possible . My blogger blog has delete by google . Now what i do . any one help me

Comment: A little bit of googling would have solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

To import from Blogger is actually very simple.

1. Log into your admin panel of WordPress
2. Go to Tools > Import
3. Select Blogger
4. Follow the instructions

You do not need any third party plugins for this, as other answers are suggesting.

More details are available on the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Blogger).

Answer (score 0):

Please see the wordpress documentation http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content or a plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/blogger-importer/

Comment: You don't need a plugin for this.  Please see my answer for how to do it in WordPress itself.

Comment: The first link of my answer is the same as your answer. the plugin was just another way